# Do we need a 4th site for the trilogy?

Tags: feature-request, scope

Right now we have server related questions on Server Fault, home user related questions on Super User and Stack Overflow for programming related questions.  There seems to be a gap for admin related questions, e.g. how to fix a desktop that won't boot, how to deal with bluescreens and other desktop related questions.  Currently many of these types of questions get dumped from Server Fault to Super User.  Right now there is no "stackoverflow" for admins

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy but not an exact dupe

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a trilogy anymore, would it?

Comment: @asmeurer: we could claim two of the sites to be part of a schizophrenic whole, and thus part of a trilogy

Comment: @asmeurer - all good trilogies are in 4 parts. or 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a gray area where the two overlap, and unfortunately I've seen single-machine admin questions get closed or moved from ServerFault.  Having said that I don't think we need another site, we just need people to exercise good judgment when making a decision on the questions.

Comment: yeah I'm just looking to see if there is any interest in a "stackoverflow" for admins- apparantly not

Answer (score 15):

Superuser is the right place for the questions that you have given as examples.

See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy

Answer (score 3):

They get dumped on SU if they are personal / individual problems. SF if it's a large scale business problem. "My Windows 7 computer won't start up after opening an `I love you` email" vs. "My web server went down and it's hosting 20 sites, I have a whole bunch of Apache mod_`s running"

Comment: it's more like "Win7 doesn't start after I/my neighbor opened *I Love You* email" goes to SU, and "20 Win7 desktops don't start after some sales dude opened *I Love You* email" goes to SF.

Answer (score 3):

> Right now we have server related questions on Server Fault [..] Right now there is no "stackoverflow" [sic] for admins

Odd. The [Server Fault FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) states (emphasis mine):

> Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. If you are in charge of ...
>
> - servers
> - networks
> - **many desktop PCs (other than your own)**
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!